# Modify Celery backend Result object

Tags: mongodb, celery

I want to store some additional data fields to the result object that celery stores on the backend.

```
{
  "_id": "<ID>",
  "status":"SUCCESS",
  "result":"8",
  "traceback":null,
  "children":[],
  "date_done":"<DATE>"
}
```

This is what is currently by mongodb collection, I want to add other fields to this object before it is saved on the backend.
( Using Celery with Rabbitmq as broker and MongoDB as the backend )